# Getting a CORS Error when running code from devtools to get json, but get no error if I open json then run code

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

I am trying to access a json file, but keep getting this error

**from origin 'chrome-search://local-ntp' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

when I try from just opening up a browser, running devtools and running some code that I wrote... However, if I open up the json file in the browser and run my code then it works.

How do I run this code so that it works when ever I run it without having to open the json file itself then run it?

```
async function GetCovidData(){
    const covidData = await fetch(JSON_I_WANT);
    const resp = await covidData.json();
    console.log(resp.filter(f=>f.prname == "Ontario"));
}

GetCovidData();
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer about using
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com along in the url where the JSON was and it worked.